# Do Excel / SQL data connections refresh both ways

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

I've created a connection in Excel that fetches some data from our SQL server. The connection string looks like:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User
>   ID=testuser;Initial Catalog=TESTDATA;Data     Source=sql-server1;Use Procedure
>   for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation
>   ID=LT-TEST;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when
>   possible=False

The plan is that the user can refresh data to get the latest updates from the server. My questions is this (since I'm very new to SQL):

If the user changes some of the data in the spreadsheet and hits refresh, will this be updated in the SQL database aswell? This would be pretty devasting.

Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of the answer, if you intend a read-only function, I'd recommend setting up a set of read-only user credentials for this circumstance

Comment: I have given the specific user the following database membership roles: public, db_datareader and db_denydatawriter. This should be enough I reckon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, changes to data in Excel will not change the table on the SQL server.

Using the built in import tools, Excel is only importing data into a worksheet by using SQL `SELECT` queries or other means. Exporting data to the server would require an `UPDATE` or `APPEND` query in SQL.

So once the user imports the data into the worksheet, they can edit all they want.